# What the duck?​

Tags: support, status-bydesign, quack-overflow, april-fools

There is a duck in the bottom right corner.

[image: Duck]

It is asking me whether it can help, absent any indication that I am indeed in need of help.

There is no "no thanks, go away" option.

The duck asks whether I have a microphone. I click "no" and it starts listening. It asks me to speak up louder.

Finally it quacks in frustration.

Did we switch target audience to 0-3 years old or something?

Edit: Ok, it goes away if you tell it you hate it. Kinda excessive tho.

Comment: Turns out the target audience is about right ... no switching needed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Ah that gave me a good laugh. "Duck is thinking, duck is typing"

Comment: The title got ruined by minimum length requirements, should have been "What the duck?"

Comment: @dtech add 2 question marks ;p

Comment: "What the Duck is going on with SO"?

Comment: @BhargavRao alas, adding question marks doesn't appear to count, spaces too.

Comment: Ah damn, the system is more intelligent than we think it is.

Comment: I love the duck! Can we have it permanently, so it can make suggestions about how to write questions? "I see you are begging for urgent treatment. Let me remind you you're talking to volunteers please. Quack!"

Comment: This duck is great (a bit quackers maybe)!

Comment: related : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308569/quack-overflow-should-also-accept-keyboard-input

Comment: BTW did anyone consider this might be offensive to a certain president, on account of a prominent duck by the name of Donald and the duck being orange and all. Seems kinda deliberate, since most rubber ducks I've seen, if not all, are actually yellow.

Comment: hehehe I thought SO guys has come up with some sort of application which listen to question and then answer em. I guess they caught me

Comment: But why won't it take NO for a microphone? Kind of weakens it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I thought that was the subjectively best part of it - it listens in spite of the absence of audio source to listen to.

Comment: @dtech Well technically it never asks for microphone permissions to the browser. So it can't actually listen to you.

Comment: its [magic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308584/347191) of the internet

Comment: I was hoping it would actually use the microphone. Note that it never *even requests access to your microphone*, let alone use it. :-P

Comment: I can't believe I fell for this year's april fool.

Comment: It's a keeper, All questions seeking debugging help should get the duck -- See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and the duck... Really, it helps `:)`

Comment: I hate this duck. It's so Clippy.

Comment: @dtech If you want a corny title, how about "If it looks like a duck..."

Comment: I have another problem. How do I bring the duck back after telling it to go away?

Comment: @AntonDementiev erase the associated cookies.

Comment: Just throw in Watson speech recognition, microphone access and let it live!!!

Comment: This forced-fun garbage is super annoying. At least let me opt out easily.

Comment: [That's the spirit](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), @G.Bach!

Comment: @halfer - fun is relative. Some are easy to amuse, others not so much. I myself have never been keen on the "today is X day, you can to do X things". I am fan of programming, not of being programmed ;)

Comment: I keep wondering what effect all that water dripping off the duck is going to have on my computer?  (A rubber duck _always_ brings up dripping-wet-fresh-from-the-bathtub imagery for me.)

Comment: This duck is amazing.  I demand more ducks on SO.

Comment: Hang on, though - the duck didn't state: 'It looks like you're writing a letter!', did it?... That's it's evil twin brother Muck!... And ... errr ... looks a lot like a paperclip...

Comment: Repressed memories of Microsoft's Clippy coming back :(

Comment: That's why I like stackoverflow. Usually, when I join some online community, nobody gives a duck.

Comment: 1. Can I sic the duck on someone? 2. Does anyone have a spare Surface Pro 4 screen I can borrow? The duck and my vintage Browning Superposed are about to have a confrontation.

Comment: Ask the expert was better.

Comment: joking about listening in using a microphone is an instant way to drive traffic AWAY from the site. the first thing I did when I saw that message was close every SO tab I had open. it's disgustingly creepy and not funny.

Comment: It's so sad when you tell the duck you hate it. They have feelings!!

Comment: Can we get a targeting scope, which follows the cursor? I want to play Duck Hunt! :-)

Comment: I love that clickbait title!

Comment: Could we please, please, please already get a permanent opt-out feature for april fools, winter hats and all other extra cruft.

Comment: Is there any way to bring up these April Fools jokes after the day is over? This duck is hilarious and it's sad to think that it will be lost forever starting tomorrow.

Comment: The duck is more annoying than the stupid winter hats.  Stack Overflow shouldn't try to annoy its users.  ...AND IT'S NOT APRIL 1 ANYMORE!

Comment: @user2023861 You must be a blast at parties.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka am I allowed to ask about permanently opting out of this stuff?  Or least any further April 2 jokes?  Or are you going to call me a "fuddy duddy"?

Comment: Indeed. It's now 16:46 UTC on April 2, and the stupid bird refuses to leave. Where is it still April 1 now? Well?

Comment: @user2023861 The thing has an "I hate this duck" option that, if you click on it, will make the duck go away permanently. Yes, you might have to repeat this 5-second process again, once per year. Oh, the humanity!

Comment: @CharlesSrstka not permanently.. it's state is stored in cookies or localStorage or whatever. We're all developers here who clear that stuff regularly. So the duck re-incarnates regularly and re-annoys regularly. I hate the duck. I hate the idea of the duck. I hate that someone wasted cognitive excess on the duck. I hate that we're having to discuss the duck in a forum. If I want laughs I'll go to comedy central tx. I'm on SO to work.

Comment: I recently asked a user whether their code (loosely described but not shown) was `while True: print("duck")` and I thought for a moment this might be revenge of some sort.

Comment: @dtech What minimum length requirements?

Comment: That's just fupduck

Comment: Oh no I missed it :(

Comment: I told it I hated it. It was so sad and went away. I realized my error and told it I want it back. Now it's there again, and we get along nicely (get it back: just delete the quack cookie from your browser).

Comment: I hope next years we will gonna have a  good old Eliza Chat Bot so People can get help with their question.

Comment: The disappearance of the duck is not a reason to close this question, the correct behavior is to accept a "duck is no more" answer.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

It's a part of Stack Exchange's annual April Fool tradition. There's even a tag for it on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools/info

As for the time, it's already April 1st in Kiribati.

Last year they tried [Dance Dance Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU), and it was pretty successful.

Comment: But its still the 31 of March.

Comment: As I already mentioned, @dtech,  it's already April 1st in Kiribati. They start it when it's April 1st somewhere in the world and end when it's April 2nd everywhere in the world. :-)

Comment: well for some reason it is there in MSE.. it does not turn up in MSO . Is it scared of meta?

Comment: @SurajRao It's not enabled on per site metas.

Comment: You should make it regional then.

Comment: @dtech, Too much work and causes confusion. Imagine if someone else had posted it here, and people from other parts of the world closes it as not repro'ble, because they can't see it?

Comment: _end when it's April 2nd everywhere in the world_ um, that is a frightening perspective..

Comment: Kinda annoying but I guess it will "fly" better if it doesn't hit on April 1st.

Comment: Thanks for implementing this, the duck solved my problem right away!

Comment: Meta fun: duck typing

Comment: could have given useful tips to new askers you know.. I think there was a meta q asking for that request.. Quack overflow could work nicely for that usecase

Comment: Am scared of just laughing out loud! Because my comment might get horribly downvoted. Duck it! Hahahahahahaha

Comment: The simple way to make duck go away: Click on duck - Press `[ctrl]` key and `[F4]` simultaneously.

Comment: On a side note, I am sure all active SO users from Kiribati appreciate that, all 3 of them.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I am very disappointed there's no way to vote down the idea.

Comment: You should have posted this after 1st Arpil :P

Comment: Duck is the next leap in AI

Comment: Pop to unlock XD XD

Comment: April fool's on stackoverflow is a horrible idea. Who comes to stackoverflow for fun? It's for work. Anything that wastes time is undesirable imho.

Comment: @geoidesic this years offering was a small duck on the bottom right of the screen. How did this waste the time of someone focussed on work and avoiding fun?

Comment: @geoidesic - it appears that many SO users are far more serious than they'd want to be. I'd say things have to be pretty bleak to find the duck amusing.

Comment: @dtech Do you mean "things have to be pretty bleak to **not** find the duck amusing" ?

Comment: @xDaizu nope, I mean that the duck is not all that amusing really, so it can only have a tangible effect if one's amusement threshold is rather low. There is a difference between "no sense of humor" and "high tolerance for humor". And then there are the people that don't have a whole lot of amusement, so even something small works, and they are willing to grab onto it.

Comment: No fun allowed!

Comment: @OchiFortune unFortunately, one cannot downvote comments.

Comment: @BhargavRao So April 1 is over everywhere in the world... is SO (seriously) continuing with the duck experiment?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - no. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308618/will-quack-overflow-be-accessible-after-the-1st/308619#comment1005505_308619

Comment: Haha April 1st, nice concept

Answer (score 108):

The duck should stay online after April 1st. It should learn new competences as time passes, such as:

- You asked a question which got downvoted or got a close vote? Ducky appears and tells you to verify that the question is in accordance to the help center.
- You are about to ask a question, which is rather short, or has 150 lines of code in it? Ducky appears and tells you to check with the rules.
- You gave an answer to a question, which is subsequently closed as duplicate? Ducky comes along and asks you to verify this answer is really needed and whether it might not be better placed at the dupe target if at all.
- You spend two hours on the site, commenting 20 or more questions without providing any answers? Ducky might pop up and tell you to get some fresh air.
- Who knows what else Ducky can learn in the months to come...

What's great about Ducky as opposed to the message popups currently on the site is that it can have a sense of humor. It can tell you things like

*"I'm a lazy writer myself, but you know what: 99% percent of questions that contain a single sentence will not be answered."*

*"Wow, did you just manage to give a complete problem description in 2 sentences? You must be the new Einstein. But my experience tell me other people will not understand your condensed writing. Why not consider adapting to their limited minds and stick to the help center rules?"*

*"I know it's tempting to just drop your complete code here. I've done it a few times myself - those questions still have no answer. I guess it's because people do not understand that `quakquakquack` is a class and `quackquak` is a number."*

*"It seems people do not like your question. You know what I normally do when that happens to me? I pretend to be one of those humans in front of the screen and read my own question out aloud. Would I understand it if I was one of them? Unfortunately not, humans are so brainy.. they need facts, verifiable examples, previous research and all the stuff from the help center. I wish they could just read my mind like my other duck friends."*

Comment: This was also [suggested in seriousness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127737/keep-the-functionality-of-clippycorn-while-removing-the-annoyance/127738) when they did "Clippy" for April Fools'. I like your suggestions for messages.

Comment: nope nope nope nope nope a thousand times nope

Comment: Even if the duck is gone, I hope somebody makes a userscript or something to bring it back.

Answer (score 57):

*Presses duck*

***DUCK:** Can I use your microphone?*

***ME:** Sure*

*No microphone access request detected*

*Checks date: 1st April*

( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Mwahahahahahaha...

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that... *feels bad about myself*

Comment: Next time, press NO.

Answer (score 41):

While I realize it's a joke (and a funny one at that), am I the only one that thinks that it could be useful as a guidance tool for newcomers and it could actually help streamline the whole *asking the first question* process a bit? It certainly catches your eye at least.

Comment: Sure, with so many newb questions barely readable or making sense, the ambiguity of foreign accents and voice recognition errors will be such an improvement. And also, undoubtedly, the NSA will tap into it and listen on everyone ;)

Comment: I also thought of the same way. I started following the steps mentioned by duck but didn't speak anything just random clicking on duck and then I realized it's april fools prank

Comment: My first thought was actually  "*FINALLY!* Them at SO *do* listen to good ideas on Meta!"

Comment: I agree with this - I've advocated for a "paperclip" bot for newcomers for a while. There are all manner of scans it could do on an in-progress question to tell them what errors they are making.

Comment: Especially in light of the duck in [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Even though it's an April joke and the duck will soon vanish, I was really hoping for some sophisticated NLP algorithm inside the duck's rubber brain that'll guide me to the relevant answer to my question.

Obviously you still have to use your fingers and type text to search for questions and answers.

Comment: I thought this is what it was and didn't even check the calander.

Answer (score 33):

You can get rid of it per site if you dont like it.

Once it goes through the entire process of quacking, it will display as follows:

[image]

Click on `I hate this duck` if you dont want to see it. 
It will show another dialog with a button `Goodbye Duck`.

Just say goodbye.

If you miss the duck later check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308576/347191) answer to make the duck forget what you said to it.

Comment: there should be "I have another problem, I hate this duck" LOL

Comment: Great, now I've hate-crimed a fictional rubber duck...

Comment: @dtech: you're allowed to hate a single duck. However, irrationally hating all rubber ducks is a different matter.

Comment: Can I get it back then?

Comment: @IllidanS4 dont think so..you told it you hate it

Comment: I guess ducks do hold grudges. At least they don't run in violent gangs. Now if it was a goose...

Comment: @IllidanS4 well you can make the duck forget your hate it seems. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308576/347191)

Comment: @halfer [It might not be irrational...](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/drop-rubber-ducky-dirty-secrets-swimming-bath-toy-study-article-1.3898442)

Comment: I don't want it to go through the entire process, I want it gone immediately.

Comment: I was disappointed I could not get rid of that big tooltip without saying "I hate it". I missed an option to just minimize it to use it later again :<

Answer (score 21):

We got our ducks in a row for our annual April 1 gag a little late this year; my apologies if anyone though the humor to be a bit fowl. Birds of a  feather, our apologies if we flightened anyone.

As sincere as this question and subsequent replies have been, I have to admit, y'all really quack me up.

But, who knows, duck-typed gags *could* be a thing of the future ... and maybe this one isn't over yet, even on the second day of the month.

Comment: Why *is* the duck still there? I thought it would disappear when Baker Island moved into the 2nd?

Comment: @MartinSmith something with April,1st being on  a Sunday.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308618/will-quack-overflow-be-accessible-after-the-1st/308619#comment1005505_308619

Answer (score 10):

You can also get rid of the duck through the Developer Console without having to wait for it to run through its full sequence.  Tested in Chrome 65, on SO, unix.SE, and vi.SE (it's a per-site cookie).

- Right-click on the duck
- Choose "Inspect"
- Paste the following into the console and hit Enter:

  ```
  $.cookie("quack", 1, {
          "path": "/",
          "expires": 3
  })
  ```

Source: [quack.en.js](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/quack.en.js?v=a261ace98e6b:formatted), line 368 as Chrome pretty-printed it:

```
$(".js-goodbye").on("click", function() {
        $.cookie("quack", 1, {
            "path": "/",
            "expires": 3
        }),
        t(),
        e()
})
```

Comment: It tricked you, didn't it? :P

Comment: I just got the [simpler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365370/whats-with-the-duck#comment569897_365371) way...

Answer (score 6):

Does the duck have a name?

Sure, for the `[python]` and `[ruby]` tags, and even for `[c++]` when you're doing metaprogramming, "duck typing" is helpful. But `[java]` users won't trust any typing unless they have a visible name to attach to it.

Comment: If he needs a name, I would go with "Dux". Sounds like a proper name for an IT related bird.

Answer (score 1):

The duck came out of an [easter egg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools/info).

You can get rid of it if you wish, but try not to be unpolite or you'll make him/her cry.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work correctly in Internet Explorer, after answering yes/no to the microphone question it just sat there and did nothing and no way to close the speech bubble.

I was basically stuck with it for 3 days, thanks guys!

Comment: Is that a bad thing?

Answer (score -5):

Poor duck!
it didn't even get the ability to duck!
instead, everything it can do is *quack*
Absolutely out of luck
what the duck?! is it a bug?

Comment: The current duck is just a duckling. Maybe Duck 2.0 will be more expressive, and will have a range of quacks in which it can give debugging advice?

Comment: Even William McGonagal's poetry was better than this :-)

Comment: @StephenC I can't decide if its worst than Paula Nancy Millstone Jennings's poetry,