# How do I disable Stack Overflow Filters (the April Fools themes)?

Tags: support, design, april-fools

I just logged on to Stack Overflow, and there was a message introducing filters. But for some reason I didn't think and reloaded the page, and then there was no filters menu. I also looked in settings, but no luck. Is there a way to turn the filters off and revert it to normal?

[image: Filter]
Browser Info:

- Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.43 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10 Version 20H2 (Build 19042.1526)
- JavaScript V8 9.8.118.4

Comment: There are [very obvious buttons](//i.stack.imgur.com/YL5cY.png) to remove this. An adblocker can be used to remove the floating button.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Where did you find this popup though? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: If the controls at the bottom are not showing up on specific browsers then that would be a [meta-tag:bug], but we'd need browser information etc to try to repro that

Comment: @HenryEcker Okay I'll update my question and add browser info

Comment: @DaCuteRaccoon An option is present at the [bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOKpI.png).

Comment: @Wolgwang At the bottom of the home page or in settings? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: It is at the bottom of every page the filter is active.

Comment: Maybe a user script is messing with it...

Comment: Or an adblocker. Disable all extensions to be sure.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the whole browser window? I just want to make sure that the buttons aren't there, and to demonstrate that they're missing, for the sake of anyone else arriving here.

Comment: I see it is 1.April. But that is the second horrible change in a few weeks. The style was already changed and page is wasted with useless infos and needed ones are removed. And now the hobbyist colors. WTF is happen here? That will be the last chance until I will move away!

Comment: With the other changes to the top banner icons/notifications this week it's hard to know if this is supposed to be a joke or not. However the big black floating Filters button was doing my head in so I enabled AdBlock for Stack Overflow and it can be removed with the manual filter `stackoverflow.com##LABEL[for="js-expand-theme-selector"]`

Comment: Note for next year: an april fool eating space on every single page (especially on a phone) with no option to turn it off completely and go back to a normal situation is the worse idea ever.

Comment: Yea this is horrible. Funny gag? no, absolute pain for your users and I bet this is disabled by this afternoon.

Comment: To disable this you'll need to checkout the secrets.....
<!--Hello Dev! Welcome to our new Filter's bar. If you need direct access to our secret keys, please go to https://s.tk/StackOverflowSecrets. (DON'T SHARE OUTSIDE THE COMPANY)-->

Comment: but it's April 2nd and it's still showing.... also maybe I'm just getting old, but I thought April Fool's day jokes were supposed to funny.   ...like [rubber duck 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365370/what-the-duck)!

Comment: I will happily pay a subscription to SO where I'm guaranteed not to receive any future April 1st "jokes".  :-)

Comment: I didn't see anything special

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There should be a rail floating at the bottom of the window that has the selector for the feature - when you scroll reach the bottom of the page, it scrolls up to sit above the footer. The first icon with the crossed out circle will revert to the default filter - Standard SO view. The X in the corner will collapse the filter rail - if it's collapsed already, you can click on the "FILTERS" logo to get it to reopen.

[image: Screenshot of page showing the bottom banner with the different icons for the views of the page. There are two freehand red circles, one on an icon indicating the default view and one around an x, indicating the ability to close the banner]

When first visiting, you also should have seen a modal pop up telling you about the feature and giving you the option to opt-out. Clicking this button is the same as choosing Default and minimizing the rail - it does not remove the Filters feature entirely.

[image: Screenshot of the modal and the opt out button circled.]

#### Possible mitigations:

If you do not see either of these, please check the following:

- Do you have any userscripts or extensions that might be preventing these from appearing properly? If so, try disabling them to find the buttons needed to remove or change the filters.
- Is your browser supported? It's possible the browser you're using isn't on [our supported list](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/). In that case, the page elements required to opt out may not appear.

If the vanilla version of the site still does not show the options to remove the filters and you are on a supported browser, please let us know through a bug report so that we can investigate what's going on. Be certain to detail your browser and system information and share a screenshot of what you're seeing as that will help us identify potential causes.

Comment: But how to remove that floating FILTERS button at all - I don't like to have it onscreen.

Comment: You can't. I confirmed it with the devs.

Comment: Bummer ... :(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((( ... I did not vote for that. Please give me possibility to remove that s...t.

Comment: It'll be gone in a day. Sooner than we could code and ship something to make it so you can remove it.

Comment: You can minimize the Filter bottom bar by pressing the X at the bottom right corner.

Comment: This filters thing is an embarrassment. Guess we're in MS territory now. Or is it Instagram.

Comment: @Asperi You have an adblocker, right? Simply add a filter rule for the `label[for='js-expand-theme-selector']` selector.

Comment: @Asperi since the whole thing seems to be an april fools joke it will be gone by tomorrow anyway... i hope.

Comment: These buttons do absolutely nothing in my browser.

Comment: @Kreiri What _is_ your browser? Do they do nothing or do they throw an error in the browser console when clicked?

Comment: Sorry, but I only see "custom filters". i did not find any button to revert to normal. The page is totally agressive colors and unreadable for me. I only can search with the browser for a text. Any chance to get the horrible collors away. Short before I unsubscribe... Bullshit!

Comment: I saw the popup on first connection and unfortunately did not click the "disable that crap^wfeature" link. Now I have a floating "filters" button eating up page space on every single page for absolutely nothing (even worse on a phone). How do I get that popup back to disable everything and get my original view back ? Thanks

Comment: thanks! the theme made my screen unreadable :(

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of the filters bar? And maybe increase the choice of filters?
Presently it only takes about 10% of real estate and is barely noticeable, could you boost it to something like 30%? An autostereogram filter is really what I'm looking for....

Comment: @Zeitounator Getting the popup back won't do what you want. It does what I explain in the answer - the equivalent of choosing the default filter and collapsing the rail at the bottom but the minimized rail isn't removed entirely.

Comment: The floating filters button Is still there taking up screen real estate and polluting screenshots of answers that just fit to the screen on mobile. What's worse is it made a horrible theme the default and you can't change it on most older browser versions because stack exchange keeps breaking Javascript every 2 weeks and raising the version bar so you can't press the buttons (or upvote or expand comments)

Comment: ...but it's April 2 and they're still there?

Comment: *Guess we're in MS territory now.* Real Clippy thinking.

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the page look for a cancel symbol and click on it.

Even in my screenshot it can be tricky to see

- look in the center for "FILTERS" and a pair of sun glasses
- the cancel button is to the right

[image: Screenshot showing cancel symbol button]

Comment: Just to add, if someone accidentally closes the Filters menu, there's a "Filters" button at the bottom right that will open it again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is on the footer of the page, click on the circle with a line through it (Ø). Then boom, its back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the Filters Toolbar, go to your browser and switch the domain from meta.stackoverflow.com to stackoverflow.com.  You should then see the toolbar and that's where you can click that lovely cancel button.

I was not initially able to see the toolbar.  I may have inadvertently agreed to the filter initially.

BTW, this had absolutely nothing to do with Ad Blockers.

Comment: Filters weren’t even available on meta.stackoverflow.com.